# Is changing this javascript helper into C++ increase the performance of the QML application?

Tags: javascript, c++, qml

I'm changin an HMI from Python/QML into C++/QML.
The QML programm uses a javascript file for some maths operations.

As i'm turning all the controller into C++, **I'm wondering if changing the javascript into C++ Q_INVOKABLE methods is a good idea.** what do you think ?

here is Helper.js

```
function radians( degrees ) {
    return degrees * 0.01745329251994329576
}

function degrees( radians ) {
    return radians * 57.29577951308232087684
}

function closestMultiple( x, multiple )
{
    if ( multiple === 0 )
        return 0
    var a = multiple * ( Math.ceil( x / multiple ) )
    var b = multiple * ( Math.floor( x / multiple ) )
    if ( Math.abs( x - a ) < Math.abs( x - b ) )
        return a
    else
        return b
}

function isMultiple( x, multiple )
{
    return ( x % multiple == 0 )
}

var list1 = []
var list2 = []

function smoothFilter( val, list, filterWidth )
{
    // on boucle sur la liste si elle est remplie
    if ( list.length === filterWidth )
    {
        list.splice( 0, 1 )
    }
    list.push( val )

    // on recupere la somme des valeurs
    var sum = 0.0
    for ( var i = 0; i < list.length; i++ )
    {
        sum += list[i]
    }

    // on calcule la moyenne
    return sum/filterWidth
}
```

Comment: SO is not learning/chatting resource. If you have no questions except explaining your code I advice you to start learning QML from the [QML book](https://qmlbook.github.io/).

Comment: my question is: Should I change the javascript helper into C++ to increase the performance of the HMI ?

Comment: By definition, C++ should be faster then JS. This makes sense in the case of heavy computations or whatever. From other side JS code is better for developing ie. changing/debugging etc. and it's not always such slow. Anyway, you always can implement both of methods and test the performance. You decide.

Comment: @QuentinGirault The simplest and most direct way to answer your question is to implement both solutions and test. Have you tried something?

Comment: not for now, I don't want to spend time if i don't know if it will be usefull. I have a lot to do. If it probably does not change a lot, I could try in a few months. Thanks for your answers btw